# Bill Number should be restart on every financial year c#

Tags: c#

Here my financial year was 1st April 2016 - 31st March 2017 = 2016-17

I have automatically Increment Bill No from BL0001. I am getting last insert record billno and increase it 1 for new bill.

```
SELECT TOP 1 billNo, billdate from Bill_Entry order by Id desc
```

But  I need to reset bill no as every financial year.

Comment: Reset to what? to the same number again? are you fine with duplicating bill numbers?

Comment: You are creating new bill number in DB itself? or using C#?

Comment: Actually you shouldn't use same bill no because if u want to search a speciifc bill no then u need to always additionally pass the financila year to get the proper record. U need to always have the date along with bill no when u search.

Comment: Anyways , can u show the code where u increment the BillNo ?

Answer (score -1):

Use this It might work for you

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('[TableName]', RESEED, NewNumber(as per your column datatype))
```

> After execute this query when you insert new data it will start with new sequence what you just given

Some Extra information

> if number=0 then in the next insert the auto increment field will contain value 1

```
Before giving auto increment number in above query, you have to make sure your existing table's auto increment column contain values less that number.
```

Comment: This assume that billNo is an IDENTITY column. Yet IDENTITY [can only be applied to numerical data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187742.aspx), which billNo obviously not, having "BL0001"